# Extending Android edittext extends to screen edge

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a relative layout with a textview and edittext. The edittext is aligned to left (or right) of textview at the same line.

How to make the edittext extends to the far edge of the screen (using xml).
Setting width is not appropriate since i might have different resolutions.

Comment: why can't you use ConstraintLayout? It's more reliable and will take care of width in landscape as well as portrait?

Comment: Is there a direct way to do it instead of going to constraintlaout?

Comment: The width is appropriate... You match the parent layout. All resolutions scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use TableLayout you can go with below code. It's possible with TableLayout also.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:shrinkColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Username"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="5"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you want to do it in Android instead of XML is if you get the width of the screen then you can put it in the dimensions for the edittext

this is the code for getting the width:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linear layout inside your relative layout. Also you can put the weight of view, so it will extend and will cover the width of device for different resolutions also.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1.0">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:text="Username"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/edit_query"
                android:hint="password"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should use 0dp width if you're using a horizontal weight. Also weights should add to the weightSum

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks... Done the required changes. It's working for me..

Comment: I see this is the hard way which i am trying to avoid. Can this be done with Tablelayout?

Comment: @alsaleem It's just a Layout... The key component is the width you set, which will span to the edge of the screen always, if you configure it correctly

Comment: @cricket_007. I used to using this way using <div>/<table> with html. I thought there is more standard way of doing it with android/xml. But it looks there isn't. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @alsaleem Like HTML, Android's XML layout elements are always laid out top-to-bottom and span the full width when you set them to